# What is a single word for "Currently Working"

Tags: synonyms

I'm listing all my work experiences on resume but for my current job I added a little label which reads "Currently Working". For some reason this doesn't seem right to me. What's the best way to specify this ?

Comment: "currently employed" is more formal but "working" works, too.

Comment: If it's a section title I'd suggest "Current employment".

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest [employed](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/employed.html);

> persons who are employed full-time or part-time during a specified payroll period. Temporary employees and those on paid-leave are included in this definition.

Read more: http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/employed.html#ixzz3T1K6aihK

Comment: I guess an example would help here, http://registry.jsonresume.org/mudassirali When you hover on that little green dot. It should say that the person is "Currently Working" here

Comment: When quoting something it is helpful to use the quote formatting, so people can tell you are using someone else's words.

Comment: @Matt E. Эллен Many thanks brother! Good to have you around.

Comment: @Mudassir Ali In that case the word Currently would suffice, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

If you have shown beginning and end dates on your prior jobs, you can simply put this (e.g.) for your current job:

- April 2012–present

(by the way, that's an en-dash, not a hyphen. Ranges of dates are separated by en-dashes.)

Comment: Yes, I do display that. So, if you look at this http://registry.jsonresume.org/mudassirali, I want a way to visually display that the person is currently associated with that organization. So, I display a little green dot which on hover would now read "Currently Working", but is it fine or can there be a more formal word for it?

Comment: Sorry, not going to advise you on software development; you seem plenty adept at that. You started this question disingenuously claiming to have a concen about YOUR resume.  I will mention, though that the verb "set up" has a space in it.

Comment: Sorry, I should have compiled the question better. The question is still about my resume but I'm making a web based resume template which could potentially be used by anyone and that's the reason why I was looking for a formal word. Thanks for educating me about the en-dash, wasn't aware of that distinction before :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about [working](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/working)? Having a paying job; employed.